# How to add approval workflow on CRM opportunity?

Tags: python, workflow, odoo

To create a workflow on opportunity, I've followed the link:

https://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/developer/3_9_Workflow_Business_Process/

On that example they work with opportunity's states attribute. I want to manage my workflow using Stage attribute. For example a sale user to move an opportunity from qualification stage to proposition, that action should be approuved by sales manager.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement that by adding a custom code to your openerp. At the moment, there is no such approval process available.